# battery model output voltage

Tags: batteries, capacitor

I'm trying to create a battery model using an equivalent circuit with a voltage source a resistor and 2 RC elements. To make it easier in this question I just used 1RC element.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpLEgw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know the parameters of the elements and the voltage of the source. (Not the same as in the schematic above)
Also the current that discharges the battery is given. (e.g. first 10 seconds 10A next 3 seconds 5A)
Now i want to calculate the output voltage. And actually it should be:

V_out= V1+R0*I+R1(I+C_1*dU_RC/dt)

Due I dont know dU_RC/dt I found this formula and think it's correct for the current step from 0A to 10A but not for the next step from 10A to 5A:

V_out= V1+R1*I+ R1*I(1-e^{-t/R1*C1})

Does anybody can help me with the derivation of the second formula based on the first one and to edit this second formula to be able to use it for more than one current step?

Comment: A battery is a strongly non-linear element with parameters depending on current levels relative to max designed capacity, history of charge-discharge (ESR, state of health, timing of discharge), and temperature. Unless this is a useless academic exercise, you can't calculate much with any definite accuracy.

Comment: Of course I do have different parameters depending on SoC, Temperature, current... I did not mention it because it does not have influence on my question

Comment: Since the functions are funny curvy non-linear, you can't have an analytical expression for the end of integration. Best you can do is to use SPICE solver.

Comment: There are already many battery models based on this circuit that reach good results compared to measurements.